# Working with 2D array in D3

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I'd like to visualize data pulled in from the census data API, specifically from the ACS survey.

The data is returned in a non-standard version of JSON, as a two-dimensional array. It basically looks like this:

```
[
[
    “POPULATION”,
    “DATE”,
    “ANOTHERTHING”
],
[
    “ALABAMA”,
    “2000”,
    “MORESTUFF”
],
[
    “ALASKA”,
    “2000”,
    “OTHERSTUFF”
],
…
]
```

I'm unfamiliar with working with this kind of JSON data, which almost looks more like a CSV, where the keys are written in the first line, and the values in every line after the first.

Is anyone familiar with how to parse and work with this data in D3, without having to go convert it first (i.e. https://gist.github.com/sarfarazansari/7e8ae05168b80b36016eb1c561a82f73)? (I'd like to draw from the data API directly).

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: do not use smart quotes (`“`)  in a JSON (or in your code, whatever it is). I reckon that your real JSON is correct, this just happened because you used a text editor, like MS Word, to write this question. Also, there is no such a thing like *non-standard JSON*, because there is no *standard JSON* to begin with. You just have a JSON which is an array of arrays, nothing special here.

That being said, you can use that exact data structure to create your charts... However, specially if you're a beginner, it's a good idea to stick with the most common (here we can say *standard*) way to organise the data in D3 codes, which is an **array of objects**.

We can easily convert that array of arrays in an array of objects, which will be more comfortable to you.

First, supposing that your array is named `data`, let's extract the headers:

```
var keys = data.shift();
```

That not only creates a headers array, but it will remove the first inner array from the data array.

Now, we iterate over each inner array, creating an object with all the key/value pairs we need:

```
var newData = data.map(function(d) {
  var obj = {};
  d.forEach(function(e, i) {
    obj[keys[i]] = e;
  });
  return obj;
});
```

There are shorter ways to do this, the one above is quite verbose but it is more didactic.

Here is a demo using the data you shared:

```js
var data = [
  [
    "POPULATION",
    "DATE",
    "ANOTHERTHING"
  ],
  [
    "ALABAMA",
    "2000",
    "MORESTUFF"
  ],
  [
    "ALASKA",
    "2000",
    "OTHERSTUFF"
  ]
];

var keys = data.shift();

var newData = data.map(function(d) {
  var obj = {};
  d.forEach(function(e, i) {
    obj[keys[i]] = e;
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(newData)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! I've combined your code with some of mine and a much larger/more detailed dataset and logged results: now, the labels that make up the first array are applied as keys to the values in each of the succeeding arrays.